# Shortest path tree different than minimum spanning tree

Tags: graph-theory

My professor brought up in class that a shortest path tree can be different than minimum spanning tree for an undirected graph. However, I have not been able to find a case where this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the shortest path is between two points, while the minimum spanning tree is the tree that spans the *entire* graph, and not just two points.

If you consider a triangle with side lengths of 1, can you see the MSP and the minimum path between all pairs of vertices in your head? do they differ for one pair of vertices?

Comment: Your explanation is correct, but  I think your example is misleading. Both minimum spanning trees and shortest path trees can be the same here. If your triangle has nodes $A$,$B$ and $C$, the tree $\{(A,B),(A,C)\}$ is the shortest path tree from source $A$, but also clearly a minimum spanning tree.

Comment: @Kuifje - I suppose I should have it more explicit which sides of the triangle I was referring to. To see the example, you need to take $A, B, C$ as the sides of the triangle, the tree as $\{(A, B), (A, C)\}$, and consider the shortest path tree from $B$ - the path to C is farther than it could be